# Integer literals

Tags: java, integer

I can't understand why in Java you can assign to a float value a double value ,for example :

```
float number=456.7F;
```

but you can't do the same for integers and float numbers, such as :

```
int numb=56798434L;
```

In C++ These things seem to work.

Comment: The questions that you do ask are not fitting your example code.

Comment: floats have decimals, ints don't.

Comment: C++ allows you to put longs into ints and doesn't have any problems?

Comment: What do you think `F` in `456.7F` stands for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot assign a value of a type with higher capacity to a type of lower capacity without casting. `long` can store larger numbers, so it can't be assigned to `int`.

Answer (score 4):

The `456.7F` literal is not a `double` value, it's `float` value. The double suffix is `d` (or absence of suffix) and it also produces a compilation error:

```
float f = 456.7d;
```

Java consistently requires an explicit casting for number transformation which may result in overflow or precision loss.